# Creating a grading system PHP

Tags: php, html

I need help finishing this code, the question is:

A student studying at university is examined by one piece of coursework and one written examination. Both components of the assessment carry a maximum of 50 marks. The following rules are used by the examiners in order to pass or fail students.

A student must score a combined total mark of 40% or more to pass.
A total of 39% is moderated to 40%.

Grades are awared on marks that fall into the following categories: 
A=100-70 B+=69-60 B=59-50 C=49-40 F=39-0.

I can’t for the life of me figure out how to complete this.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Commision</title>

    <h1>Result of sale commision </h1>
    <?php
        $coursework=$_POST['coursework'];
        if ($coursework>=50) {
            echo ' Your coursework grade cannot be above 50 ';
        } elseif ($coursework<=51) { 
            print "<p>Your initial coursework grade is" .$coursework."</p>"; 
        }
        $written=$_POST['written'];
        if ($written>=50) {
            echo ' written grade cannot be above 50 ';
        } elseif ($written<=51) {
            print "<p> Your initial written grade is" .$written."</p>";
        }

        $total= $written + $coursework;
        print "<p>Your total grade combine is " .$total."</p>";
    ?>
</html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Commision</title>

    <h1>Grade calculator </h1>
    <p>This form will allow you to work out grades</p>

    <h2>Provide your grades </h2>

    <form name="commision" action="graderesp.php" method="POST">
        <p>Enter your written examination mark: <input type="text" name="written"></p>
        <p>Enter your coursework mark: <input type="text" name="coursework"></p>

        <p>Thank you for your salary <input type="submit" name="continue" value="Continue" /></p>
    </form>
</html>
```

Comment: where's the form for this? I can't see this failing otherwise, if something in that form isn't correct.

Comment: edit your question instead http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41474741/edit and delete code from comments please

Comment: Its more I cant figure out how to then use the total of the two figures to get a grade from a number say I got 60 total how do I then say they receive an B+?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what is exactly what you are trying to achieve ? A code that gives you your grade ( in categories ) based on the provided 2 scores ?

You could implement switch statment in order to achieve this. The pseudo code goes like this:

```
$workScore = $_POST['coursework'];

switch($workScore) {
case $workScore >= 70 and $workScore <= 100:
    echo 'Your Grade is A';
    break;
case $workScore >= 60 and $workScore <= 69:
    echo 'Your Grade is B+';
    break;
case $workScore >= 59 and $workScore <= 60:
    echo 'Your Grade is B';
    break;
default:
echo 'something else':
}
```

Then after you have both results: written and work, then you calculate you final score and send it to the end user

Comment: Thanks Sergio that helped fix my code. if I was to then add a new component that each individual grade must be passed with a minimum of 15% and if 40% is achieved but doesn't achieve minimum is failed to 39%? how would I do that?

Comment: You will need to then , add a new validation before the switch statement in order to check if the parameter grade is greater than 15% if is, then continue with switch, if it is not, then break the code and do not enter the switch code, since it is not longer necessary, they have failed before. If after that, you need more validations, for example, they send a grade greater than 15% but the sum of them does not reach the 40%   that must be done after the switch and replace the result of that operation. Good luck with your project/homework